# Can I copy and invert an adjustment brush layer in Adobe Lightroom CC?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, photo-editing

In Adobe Lightroom CC I created an adjustment brush layer and can apply effects within that area, but I would like to also apply effects outside the area. I assume copying the brush layer and inverting it is the solution, but there may be other solutions.

1. Can I copy and invert an adjustment brush layer in Adobe Lightroom CC?
2. Any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Hi Bart, what have you tried so far? Did you try copying it and then inverting? If so, did it work? If not, please do :) It shows that you have put in some effort in solving it yourself. If you run into issues along the way, please edit your question and somebody will help you out.

Comment: Tried a whole bunch of things, copying and inverting does not work. I ended up using 4 to 6 gradient filters to be able to "target" the background. Not the best solution.

Comment: Ok, that's great that you've looked into possible solutions! Could you please add that to your question by editing it? Be as complete as possible, so do add *why* it did not work as you would like it to. Maybe even add a screenshot that shows the issue.